# Good Idea to open a connection again in Catch Block?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am dealing with some JDBC connections inside a try-catch block. I have a connection open inside a try block as follows:

```
try{

// One JDBC Connection is established here 

}

catch(SQLException ex)

{

// Should I open new connection here or use the above one??
}
```

Since, I want to insert some records once the exception is caught, hence I am wondering whether it's a good idea to open a new connection to the same database again for which a connection has already been established in the try block ? Basically I just need to use different table inside the catch block for the same database for which the connection has already been established.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Just use the same connection.

Comment: @Salah Depends on if the exception is closed connection

Comment: You could also use a connection pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only exception you should create a new connection for is closed connection. Otherwise continue using the same connection.

- Below assumes you will want to re-run the method.

Once you catch that exception, if you create another connection you will have to recursively call the original method.

So, only thing that should scare you is infinite recursion. If you make a check to combat that then you will be fine.

Comment: I will need that connection again after doing something in the catch block therefore as you suggested I should stick with original connection. Thanks !

Comment: I have the following `Connection connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("//my urls here"); ` in my try block and trying to use `connRemote` again in my catch block but getting "Cannot find symbol for connRemote" error in netbeans. Do you know why?

Comment: @John It's because connRemote is only in the scope of the Try block. Move the field up one scope to access it in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy would be for you to stick with the original connection. You do not need a new one as one has already been established.